# Fast way to multiply permutation groups?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm having some trouble with permutation group multiplication. When multiplying permutation groups, I always follow the method described in this post: [Multiplication in Permutation Groups Written in Cyclic Notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/multiplication-on-permutation-group-written-in-cyclic-notation)

Suppose, we have two cycles:

a ⇨ (opqrstu)(hijklmn)(abcdefg)

b ⇨ (gmr)(fku)(eiq)(dnt)(clp)(bjs)(aho)

Suppose I would like to calculate some products of these cycles: a², a³, ab, ab², a²b³, ... Is there a 'fast' / computer based way to calculate these results? I suppose you could do it by hand, but that's going to take a very long time and is prone to errors...

Comment: Seems like you are asking about multiplying permutations, not permutation groups.

Comment: Using computer, you can **multiply permutations** in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) - see [this documentation](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap42.html)