# order of a symmetric group 7

Tags: abstract-algebra

$S_7$, the symmetric group on 7   letters.

Find the order of $\pi$ where

$$ \pi = \begin{bmatrix}  
               1&  2 & 3  & 4&  5 & 6 & 7 
                     \\ 2 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 6  
            \end{bmatrix}$$

---

its 7 yes?? I am trying to do the permutations but any element of the group is suppose to divide the order of $S_7$?

I am doing the permutations on scratch paper. I am on $\pi^4=$ and its not looking like $e$

---

**Work in progress**

computing $\pi * \pi $

$$ \begin{aligned}
\pi * \pi 
=\begin{bmatrix}  
               1&  2 & 3  & 4&  5 & 6 & 7 
                     \\ 2 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 6  
            \end{bmatrix}
*\begin{bmatrix}  
               1&  2 & 3  & 4&  5 & 6 & 7 
                     \\ 2 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 6  
            \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

$$ \begin{aligned}
   1 \to 2 \to 3
\\ 2 \to 3 \to 7
\\3 \to 7 \to 6
\\4 \to 5 \to 1
\\5 \to 1 \to 2
\\6 \to 4 \to 5
\\7 \to 6 \to 9
\end{aligned}$$

making $$
\pi^2= \begin{bmatrix}  
               1&  2 & 3  & 4&  5 & 6 & 7 
                     \\ 3 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 5& 4  
            \end{bmatrix}
 $$

computing $\pi^3 $

$$ \pi^3 =\pi^2 * \pi = \begin{bmatrix}  
               1&  2 & 3  & 4&  5 & 6 & 7 
                     \\ 7 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 5  
            \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}  
               1&  2 & 3  & 4&  5 & 6 & 7 
                     \\ 2 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 6  
            \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ \begin{aligned}
   1 \to 2 \to 7
\\ 2 \to 3 \to 6
\\3 \to 7 \to 4
\\4 \to 5 \to 2
\\5 \to 1 \to 3
\\6 \to 4 \to 1
\\7 \to 6 \to 5
\end{aligned}$$

making $$
\pi^3= \begin{bmatrix}  
               1&  2 & 3  & 4&  5 & 6 & 7 
                     \\ 7 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 5  
            \end{bmatrix}
 $$

Comment: Yes, it's order 7. Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/multiplication-in-permutation-groups-written-in-cyclic-notation , may be helpful to you

Comment: The order of $S_7$ is $7!$, and $7$ certainly divides $7!$.

Comment: "I am on $\pi^4$ and it's not looking like $e$" . Of course not - keep going!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quicker method would be to use the one line cycle notation for $\pi$,
$$\pi = (1\;2\; 3\; 7\; 6\; 4\; 5).$$
This is just one 7-cycle, so the order is 7.

Answer (score 1):

"Order of permutation of a finite set 
 in disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of length of cycles." 
As you can see 
The permutation here has 
$$\pi=(1 2 3 7 4 6 5 )$$ which is the only disjoint cycle ,and of length 7 .
Hence the order of $\pi$ is 7 .

Comment: You just answered using the same argument as the already accepted answer.

Comment: @mucciolo Pardon me sir ,but I thought "with a theorem" answer would be better for upcoming readers of the question .