# Convert $(123)(456)(1457)$ into a disjoint cycle

Tags: permutation-cycles

I am struggling to solve this. According to $(123)$, $1$ gets sent to $2$, but according to $(456)(1457)$, $1$ gets sent to $5$. Can this be decomposed?

Comment: Read this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/multiplication-in-permutation-groups-written-in-cyclic-notation

Comment: You are right; $(456)(1457)$ sends $1$ to $5$.  Now $(1,2,3)$ leaves $5$ fixed, so ...

Answer (score 2):

$$1\stackrel{(1\,4\,5\,7)}\longmapsto 4 \stackrel{(4\,5\,6)}\longmapsto 5\stackrel{(1\,2\,3)}\longmapsto 5$$
$$5\stackrel{(1\,4\,5\,7)}\longmapsto 7 \stackrel{(4\,5\,6)}\longmapsto 7\stackrel{(1\,2\,3)}\longmapsto 7$$
$$7\stackrel{(1\,4\,5\,7)}\longmapsto 1 \stackrel{(4\,5\,6)}\longmapsto 1\stackrel{(1\,2\,3)}\longmapsto 2$$
$$2\stackrel{(1\,4\,5\,7)}\longmapsto 2 \stackrel{(4\,5\,6)}\longmapsto 2\stackrel{(1\,2\,3)}\longmapsto 3$$
$$3\stackrel{(1\,4\,5\,7)}\longmapsto 3 \stackrel{(4\,5\,6)}\longmapsto 3\stackrel{(1\,2\,3)}\longmapsto 1$$
so that one of the cycles is
$$(1\,5\,7\,2\,3). $$
$$4\stackrel{(1\,4\,5\,7)}\longmapsto 5 \stackrel{(4\,5\,6)}\longmapsto 6\stackrel{(1\,2\,3)}\longmapsto 6$$
$$6\stackrel{(1\,4\,5\,7)}\longmapsto 6 \stackrel{(4\,5\,6)}\longmapsto 4\stackrel{(1\,2\,3)}\longmapsto 4$$
so that another cycles is
$$(4\,6) $$
and there cannot be more.