# For each element $\sigma $ of the group $S_{3}$ of permutations of degree 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I find the order m of each element $\sigma $ and find the subgroup { $e,\sigma,\sigma^{2},···,\sigma^{m−1}$ } generated by such element?

Comment: Recall that element order divides group order. There aren't that many divisors of $|S_3|$ ;)

Comment: The phrasing of your Question could be clearer.  Are you interested in one specific element $\sigma \in S_3$ or in all of them?  Please include the context of your problem, such as where the problem occurs or what approach you've already explored.

Comment: The order of the group of permuatation of $n$ letters is $n!$ by Langrange theorem we know that if $H$ is a subgroup then the order of $H$ divides $n!$ so you need to know the diviseur of $n!$

Comment: @hardmath I am interested in all of them, I did mis phrase the question, it is edited to be more feasible now.

Comment: Are you able to explicitly write down an element of $S_3$ (as a permutation), then find its successive powers (as composed permutations)?

Comment: @EricTowers Well I know that S3 can be separated into: {e,(1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2)} however I don't know how I would go about finding its successive powers.

Comment: You seem to be saying "powers of the group."  No.  Pick an element.  Find its successive powers.  Do you know how to find the product of permutations?

Comment: @erictowers Well using the elements listed above, if I singled out say (1,3), I know it's product in the context of the subgroup would be {e, (1,3), $(1,3)^2$,..., $(1,3)^m-1$} but I don't know how to expand such products.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/multiplication-in-permutation-groups-written-in-cyclic-notation

Comment: @EricTowers that's perfect, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to help!